# Show Map Pins on a Custom Map Image

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have on my site currently a map showing lots of pins in a google map. This is driven by a database of lat/long items.

The Google Map is overkill in my case, Ideally I would obtain a nice outline image of my country (UK) and plot the pins directly onto it. Its just to show "coverage".

Does anyone know of a good approach to this?

Comment: Is the quantity of pins so high that it would prevent you from creating some sort of custom static image?  Google Maps is ideal for interaction vs static display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use canvas to plot points on an image, but that will probably be more trouble than using Google Maps.  You would have to find a way to convert the lat/lng data into x,y pixel coordinates.

What I would do is stitch the outline image to a Google Map, then you can use Google's  `OverlayView` methods to plot the points in the correct place.

Google has an example of this in the API reference [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple.html).

You could disable all of the navigation tools on the map and give the impression of a static image on your page while still being able to add new points later if needed.